# abnormal performance issues with convolutional network

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

For a couple of days I have had a seemingly unsolvable problem. I'm trying to solve a classification task with a convo-network:

```
def cnn_net(input_layer, labels, dropout):
"""Model function for CNN."""
i = 0
i += 1
shape = [2, 2, 1, 8]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_layer, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv1, b))
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [4, 4, 8, 8]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv2, b))
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [8, 8, 8, 8]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv3, b))
pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [8, 8, 8, 8]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool3, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv4, b))
pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [8, 8, 8, 16]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool4, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv5 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv5, b))
pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [16, 16, 16, 16]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv6 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool5, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv6 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv6, b))
pool6 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv6, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [16, 16, 16, 16]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv7 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool6, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv7 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv7, b))
pool7 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv7, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [32, 32, 16, 32]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv8 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool7, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv8 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv8, b))
pool8 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv8, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [220, 220, 32, 16]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv9 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool8, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv9 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv9, b))
pool9 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv9, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

i += 1
shape = [70, 70, 16, 1]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[shape[-1]]))
conv10 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool9, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv' + str(i))
conv10 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(conv10, b))
pool10 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv10, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', name='conv_pool_' + str(i))

last_layer = pool10

print last_layer.get_shape().as_list()
#dim = reduce(operator.mul, [int(x) for x in last_layer.shape[1:]], 1)
dim = 256
reduced = 512

# Dense Layer
output_flat = tf.reshape(last_layer, [-1, dim])

dense_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([dim, reduced], stddev=0.1))
dense_b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[reduced]))
dense1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(output_flat, dense_w)+dense_b)
dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense1, rate=dropout)

dense_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([reduced, 3], stddev=0.1))
dense_b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[3]))
logits = tf.matmul(dropout1, dense_w) + dense_b
losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=labels)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)

train_operation = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

return logits, train_operation, loss
```

the training itself looks like that:

```
image_size = (400, 400)
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, image_size[0], image_size[1], 1], name='input_data')
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int8, [None, 3], name='targets')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
logits, train_op, train_loss = cnn_net(inputs, targets, keep_prob)
session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(LOG)
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    print "Model restored..."
else:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(session, LOG + "model.ckpt", 0)
    print "New model created"
tf.get_default_graph().finalize()

if TRAIN_FLAG == 'train':
    print 'train...'
    train_count = 0
    valid_set = tuple(chart_generator(batch_size, window_size, observation_size, image_size, valid=True))
    train_set = tuple(chart_generator(batch_size, window_size, observation_size, image_size))
    for i in range(epochs):
        traind_scores = []
        ii = 0
        epoch_loss = []
        for X_batch, y_batch in train_set:
            train_count += 1
            # for k in range(16):
            #     print y_batch[k]
            #     cv2.imshow('chart', X_batch[k])
            #     cv2.waitKey(1000)
            t = time.time()
            print 'starting...'
            print X_batch.shape, y_batch.shape
            _, c = session.run((train_loss, train_op), feed_dict={inputs: X_batch, targets: y_batch, keep_prob: 0.5})
```

Input data has shape (32, 400, 400, 1) and target data has shape (32, 3). My PC is running linux mint with GPU Nvidia GTX 1070 I tested Cuda 8 (TF 1.3) and cudNN 6 and switched to Cuda 9 (TF 1.5) with cudNN 7 in order to find out whats wrong. If I start training, tensorflow tells me that it found my GPU and everything is fine. But the first training iteration (32 images in one batch) took 5.2 hours, every training step after that took 45 seconds.

A couple of weeks ago I trained on this machine another fully-convolutional network way bigger, with 0.2 seconds per iteration:

```
def inference_conv(self, image, keep_prob=1.0):
        """
        Semantic segmentation network definition
        :param image: input image. Should have values in range 0-255
        :param keep_prob:
        :return:
        """
        conv1 = self.complete_conv2d(image, [9, 9, self.NUM_CHANNELS, 16], tf.nn.relu)
        conv2 = self.complete_conv2d(conv1, [9, 9, 16, 16], tf.nn.relu)
        pool1 = self.max_pool_2x2(conv2)
        conv3 = self.complete_conv2d(pool1, [9, 9, 16, 32], tf.nn.relu)
        conv4 = self.complete_conv2d(conv3, [3, 3, 32, 32], tf.nn.relu)
        pool2 = self.max_pool_2x2(conv4)
        conv5 = self.complete_conv2d(pool2, [3, 3, 32, 32], tf.nn.relu)
        # conv6 = complete_conv2d(conv5, [3, 3, 32, 32], True)
        # conv7 = complete_conv2d(conv6, [3, 3, 32, 32], True)
        conv8 = self.complete_conv2d(conv5, [3, 3, 32, 32], tf.nn.relu)
        pool3 = self.max_pool_2x2(conv8)
        conv9 = self.complete_conv2d(pool3, [3, 3, 32, 64], tf.nn.relu)
        # conv10 = complete_conv2d(conv9, [3, 3, 64, 64], True)
        # conv11 = complete_conv2d(conv10, [3, 3, 64, 64], True)
        conv12 = self.complete_conv2d(conv9, [5, 5, 64, 64], tf.nn.relu)
        pool4 = self.max_pool_2x2(conv12)
        conv13 = self.complete_conv2d(pool4, [5, 5, 64, 128], tf.nn.relu)
        # conv14 = complete_conv2d(conv13, [3, 3, 128, 128], True)
        # conv15 = complete_conv2d(conv14, [3, 3, 128, 128], True)
        conv16 = self.complete_conv2d(conv13, [5, 5, 128, 128], tf.nn.relu)

        pool5 = self.max_pool_2x2(conv16)
        conv17 = self.complete_conv2d(pool5, [7, 7, 128, 256], tf.nn.relu)
        dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(conv17, keep_prob=keep_prob)
        conv18 = self.complete_conv2d(dropout1, [1, 1, 256, 256], tf.nn.relu)
        dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout(conv18, keep_prob=keep_prob)
        conv19 = self.complete_conv2d(dropout2, [1, 1, 256, self.NUM_OF_CLASSESS])
        dropout3 = tf.nn.dropout(conv19, keep_prob=keep_prob)

        deconv1 = self.deconv(dropout3, [4, 4, 64, self.NUM_OF_CLASSESS], tf.shape(pool4), activation=tf.nn.relu)
        fuse1 = tf.add(deconv1, pool4)

        deconv2 = self.deconv(fuse1, [4, 4, 32, 64], tf.shape(pool3), activation=tf.nn.relu)
        fuse2 = tf.add(deconv2, pool3)

        shape = tf.shape(image)
        deconv_shape2 = tf.stack([shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], self.NUM_OF_CLASSESS])
        deconv3 = self.deconv(fuse2, [16, 16, self.NUM_OF_CLASSESS, 32], deconv_shape2, stride=8, activation=tf.nn.relu)

        return deconv3
```

if I start this training now, its still 0.2 seconds while the other one needs hours... does anyone know whats wrong with my code? The new network has way fewer parameters and the same error function. The only difference is the fully connected layer (the larger network is a segmentation network without any fully-connected layer).